# Remove HTML tags in String

Tags: c#, html

How can I remove HTML tags from the following string?

```
<P style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 10pt" class=MsoNormal><SPAN style="LINE-HEIGHT: 115%; 
FONT-FAMILY: 'Verdana','sans-serif'; COLOR: #333333; FONT-SIZE: 9pt">In an 
email sent just three days before the Deepwater Horizon exploded, the onshore 
<SPAN style="mso-bidi-font-weight: bold"><b>BP</b></SPAN> manager in charge of 
the drilling rig warned his supervisor that last-minute procedural changes were 
creating "chaos". April emails were given to government investigators by <SPAN 
style="mso-bidi-font-weight: bold"><b>BP</b></SPAN> and reviewed by The Wall 
Street Journal and are the most direct evidence yet that workers on the rig 
were unhappy with the numerous changes, and had voiced their concerns to <SPAN 
style="mso-bidi-font-weight: bold"><b>BP</b></SPAN>’s operations managers in 
Houston. This raises further questions about whether <SPAN 
style="mso-bidi-font-weight: bold"><b>BP</b></SPAN> managers properly 
considered the consequences of changes they ordered on the rig, an issue 
investigators say contributed to the disaster.</SPAN></p><br/>
```

I'm writing it to Asponse.PDF, but the HTML tags are shown in the PDF. How can I remove them?

Comment: i tried HTMLDecode, didn't work

Comment: You need to HTML encode to escape the tags.

Comment: Do you want to strip the tags or apply the formatting?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags

Answer (score 106, accepted):

**Warning:** `This does not work for all cases and should not be used to process untrusted user input.`

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
const string HTML_TAG_PATTERN = "<.*?>";

static string StripHTML (string inputString)
{
   return Regex.Replace 
     (inputString, HTML_TAG_PATTERN, string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: -1 You shouldn't use a regular expression to parse a context-free grammar like HTML. If the HTML is being provided by some external entity, then it can be easily manipulated to evade your regular expression.

Comment: `public static string StripTagsCharArray(string source)
    {
 char[] array = new char[source.Length];
 int arrayIndex = 0;
 bool inside = false;

 for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
 {
     char let = source[i];
     if (let == '<')
     {
  inside = true;
  continue;
     }
     if (let == '>')
     {
  inside = false;
  continue;
     }
     if (!inside)
     {
  array[arrayIndex] = let;
  arrayIndex++;
     }
 }
 return new string(array, 0, arrayIndex);
    }` It is about 8x time faster than Regex

Comment: @mehaase For the most part I agree. But who said anything about parsing? He simply wants to remove tags. A fundamental distinction must always be made between really PARSING html with regex versus SEARCHING or MATCHING some html with regex.

Comment: @capdragon There is no difference. In order to transform the document *correctly*, you must parse it according to the rules of the context free grammar that governs it. (Emhasis on the word "correct". Your example works for some test cases but is not "correct" in the general case.) A truly regular language cannot be used to parse a context free grammar (see: Chomsky's hierarchy). Run your code on this string: `<p foo=">">Bar</script>` The result should be `Bar` but your code produces  `">Bar`.

Comment: @capdragon Furthermore, people extrapolate from examples they see on SO. Eventually somebody will read this and try to rewrite it to just remove <script> tags, and they will not realize that's it's especially not suitable for XSS-prevention (since it can easily be tricked). On SO, I believe solutions should be written for the general audience reading it, not just for the single person who asked the question. (Otherwise, why post the question and answer publicly in the first place?)

Comment: @mehaase We'll have to agree to disagree because I think you're wrong on both accounts: 1) There IS a difference and `<p foo=">">Bar</script>` is not HTML. 2) This question has over 50 up-votes so how you came to the conclusion that it's not suitable for the general audience and benefits a single person who asked the question is beyond me.

Furthermore, I noticed you didn't post an answer to the question, perhaps you can suggest a better solution?

Comment: If you want valid HTML5, how about `<p data-foo=">">Bar</script>`? But keep in mind that some people *will* use your code to process HTML of unknown provenance, and that HTML is not guaranteed to be valid! I would support your answer if you prefaced it with, "Warning: This does not work for all cases and should not be used to process untrusted user input." I suspect you have 58 upvotes because 58 people (living and dead) on the planet either aren't aware of or don't mind the test cases in which your solution is incorrect.

Comment: @mehaase fair enough. I made the changes, thanks.

Comment: @Alex V. Kostyukov this code can be tricked by some strings. For example: "10 < 20 <a href="#">" it will produce "10 " only

Comment: @AlexV.Kostyukov Hi Alex! You are right, this is about 8x times faster than an uncompiled regex, but try to compile it :)

Comment: @WoIIe I dont not have any problem with compiling this code

Answer (score 10):

You should use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
HtmlDocument doc = ...
string text = doc.DocumentElement.InnerText;
```

Comment: I really don't see why people give the answer to use the Agility Pack, since .InnerText of the body (as an example) doesn't render a markup-free string. There are plenty of people on SO who get the Agility Pack then wonder why they're still staring at markup, script tags.

Comment: Seemed to work for me pretty well. Certainly more elegant than any of the solutions above.

Comment: This solutions just removes wrapping HTML tags, does not guarantee that all markup will be removed