# Finding certain text and filtering the rest out

Tags: c#, regex, http

Let's say I have this string(huge), and I want to filter out everything but what I'm looking for. Here's an example of what I want:

```
<strong>You</strong></font> <font size="3" color="#05ABF8">
<strong>Shook</strong></font> Me All <font size="3" color="#05ABF8">
<strong>Night</strong></font> <font size="3" color="#05ABF8">
<strong>Long</strong></font> mp3</a></div>
```

As you can see, There's text in between all that. I want to get "You Shook Me All Night Long" and take out the rest. How will I go by accomplishing this?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878452/remove-html-tags-in-string and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags

Comment: and/or http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/414076

Comment: What about "mp3", do you need to capture it too?

Comment: @ Maxim, yes I wanted that too. Anyways, Mate's response got me the help I needed. Here's the code I found helpful: `String result = Regex.Replace(htmldoc, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex: `>([\s|\w]+)<`

```
var input = @"
<strong>You</strong></font> <font size='3' color='#05ABF8'>
<strong>Shook</strong></font> Me All <font size='3' color='#05ABF8'>
<strong>Night</strong></font> <font size='3' color='#05ABF8'>
<strong>Long</strong></font> mp3</a></div>";

var regex = new Regex(@">(?<match>[\s|\w]+)<");

var matches = regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>()
   // Get only the values from the group 'match'
   // So, we ignore '<' and '>' characters
   .Select(p => p.Groups["match"].Value);
```

[image: Matches]

```
// Concatenate the captures to one string
var result = string.Join(string.Empty, matches)
    // Remove unnecessary carriage return characters if needed
    .Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
```

[image: The result]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have valid start tags for the ending `</a></div>` at the end of your xml/html you posted.

```
string value = XElement.Parse(string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", yourstring)).Value;
```

Or a method that strips Html:

```
public static string StripHTML(this string HTMLText)
{
    var reg = new Regex("<[^>]+>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return reg.Replace(HTMLText, "").Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
}
```

Comment: You should not use LINQ2XML to parse an html