# Find all 'more or less than' characters which is not tags in xml

Tags: c#, xml, regex

I need a regex to find all '<' or '>' which is not xml-tags.

Example:

```
<tag1>W<E><E</tag1>Z<>S
```

Should find

```
<><<>
```

Example:

```
<tag1>W<E><E</E></tag1>Z<>S
```

Should find

```
<<>
```

So, any hits where '<' or '>' is not in a tag (yes we alos have al self-closing tags which should be taken into consideration :)

**Edit #2:**
What I want to do in the end is to replace all matches with the html-encoded values.

**Edit #3:**

So what I want to do is from a text containing HTML with some additional tags (very few known tags) get all '<' and '>' which is not included in the tags.

Example (the bold ones I want to find so I can replace them with their encoded values):

```
<div>
  <a href="link">Link with < characters</a>
  <knownTag>Text with character ></knownTag>
  <knownTag>Text < again ></knownTag>
<div>
```

Result should be:

```
<div>
  <a href="link">Link with &lt; characters</a>
  <knownTag>Text with character &gt;</knownTag>
  <knownTag>Text &lt; again &gt;</knownTag>
<div>
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: why [regex](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: `<tag1>` and `<E>` are not valid HTML either. And the self-closing rules are different in various HTML versions/flavors.

Comment: What you want doesn't make sense, you want to match `<E>` but it's still valid, since in HTML5 you *can* use `<img>` or `<br>` for example.

Comment: Sorry for my bad description. My string will contain self-defined tags. So I have updated my question a bit.

Comment: @Carl-OttoKjellkvist: if i understand well, the "tag" name don't matter. In this case, why do you want to remove <> around <E> in your first example, that is a self-closing and defined by you (see the second example) tag?

Comment: In the first example the tag is not closed :)

Comment: You are better off with a parser ...

Comment: Please give me info about a parser which can help med with this issue. I have looked into HTMLAgilityPack but what I can see this is not possible.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: The sad part is, I could do this with a single regular expression.  But even as an occassional XMl/HTML regex parsing person, I have to say the regex solution for this would break my developer standards of maintaining Readability, and also... would only work with the .Net flavor of Regex.  What you need is an XML Tag finder, which either requires that a tag self-close `<br />`, or that at some point, there is a properly nested closing equivilent.  I think HTMLAgilityPack with the ability to view InnerText would be a great solution personally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with regex; however, it's not as simple as you suggest.  You will need to find valid tags and process them in order to make this work.  It just so happens that I did this some time ago when writing a fast and lightwieght xml/html parser.  The code is available at:

http://csharptest.net/browse/src/Library/Html/XmlLightParser.cs
http://csharptest.net/browse/src/Library/Html/XmlLightInterfaces.cs

To use the parser, you will implement the defined interface `IXmlLightReader` from the later of the two source files.  The following example produces your desired results, and also handles several other capabilities you did not mention, like CDATA sections, processing instructions, DTDs, etc.

```
class RegexForBadXml
{
    const string Input = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<div>\r\n\t<a href=\"link\">Link with < characters</a>\r\n\t<knownTag>Text with character > &and other &#BAD; stuff</knownTag>\r\n\t<knownTag>Text < again ></knownTag>\r\n\t<knownTag><![CDATA[ Text < again > ]]></knownTag>\r\n<div>";

    private static void Main()
    {
        var output = new StringWriter();
        XmlLightParser.Parse(Input, XmlLightParser.AttributeFormat.Html, new OutputFormatter(output));
        Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
    }

    private class OutputFormatter : IXmlLightReader
    {
        private readonly TextWriter _output;
        public OutputFormatter(TextWriter output)
        {
            _output = output;
        }

        void IXmlLightReader.StartDocument() { }
        void IXmlLightReader.EndDocument() { }

        public void StartTag(XmlTagInfo tag)
        {
            _output.Write(tag.UnparsedTag);
        }

        public void EndTag(XmlTagInfo tag)
        {
            _output.Write(tag.UnparsedTag);
        }

        public void AddText(string content)
        {
            _output.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(content)));
        }

        public void AddComment(string comment)
        {
            _output.Write(comment);
        }

        public void AddCData(string cdata)
        {
            _output.Write(cdata);
        }

        public void AddControl(string cdata)
        {
            _output.Write(cdata);
        }

        public void AddInstruction(string instruction)
        {
            _output.Write(instruction);
        }
    }
}
```

The preceeding program outputs the following results:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<div>
    <a href="link">Link with &lt; characters</a>
    <knownTag>Text with character &gt; &amp;and other &amp;BAD; stuff</knownTag>
    <knownTag>Text &lt; again &gt;</knownTag>
    <knownTag><![CDATA[ Text < again > ]]></knownTag>
<div>
```

Note: I added the xml declaration, CDATA, and '&' text for testing only.

Comment: Thank you for this...  a portion of your code now lives on in one of my projects (with credits of course)

Answer (score 3):

use one of method from [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878452/remove-html-tags-in-string) and remove html tags of the input

then

```
string output = new string(input.ToCharArray().Where(c=> c=='<'||c=='>').ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your example, it seems you are not searching XML files as the subject suggests, but rather XML-like files - perhaps files that would be XML if they did not contain the "<" and ">" characters that you are looking for.

But you have not specified the task clearly enough. What should happen, for example, with

```
<tag1>xxxx</tag2>
```

or with

```
<tag1><x a="</tag1>"/></tag1>
```

Picking up the second case is pretty tough (perhaps impossible) to achieve with regular expressions alone. You need to define the grammar or the input language you want to accept (an extension of XML) and parse it using recursive parsing techniques.

Comment: What I have is an HTML page with some additional tags which I add. Then the user needs to be able to add '<' and '>'. So your examples above is ignorable, example 1 is not valid and example 2 is not needed to be considered.

Comment: OK, it sounds as if you understand the problem well enough to write a much better specification than you have given us.

Answer (score 0):

In your limited case it seems that there's an algorithm strategy that might work, which can be outlined as follows:

1. Search left to right for an open tag, i.e. `<something>`.
2. If found, search the remaining string for the matching close tag, `</something>`
3. Recursively repeat steps one and two for the string between the open and close tags just found for as long as you can find matching pairs
4. For sequences of the string where no open/close tag pair is found,
   replace all occurrences of `<` and `>` with the escapes.

Comment: I hasten to add that this is NOT fool-proof, e.g. it does not properly handle nested tags of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand too much from your question but I wrote a code that takes your HTML example and return the same HTML result with your expected HTML result.

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(YourHTML, @"(?<=<.*?>).+(?=<.*?>)");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    YourHTML = YourHTML.Replace(match.Value, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(match.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the new formulation of your problem in edit #3, I think you could solve it with a regular expression that matches "<" followed by a negative lookahead

```
<(?!(/?(a|b|div|p|....|!--|!\[CDATA\[))
```

which matches `<` if not followed by one of the known tag-names, and then replace this `"<"` with `"&lt;"`

Answer (score 0):

```
    static string test(string input)
    {
        var r = @"(<(.*?)>)(.*?)</\2>";
        while (Regex.IsMatch(input, r))
            input = Regex.Replace(input, r, "$3");
        return Regex.Replace(input, @"\w", "");
    }
```