# Get only text of Item from ItemAttachment (EWS Managed API)

Tags: c#, properties, attachment, ews-managed-api

Is there a way to remove HTML tags from Item which is from `ItemAttachment`?
I can get only text from Item. But not from Item which is from `ItemAttachment`.
Here is my code:

```
foreach (ItemAttachment itemAttach in item.Attachments.OfType<ItemAttachment>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(itemAttach.Name);

    itemAttach.Load();

    PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet();
    propSet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
    propSet.BasePropertySet = BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties;

    itemAttach.Item.Load(propSet);

    Console.WriteLine(itemAttach.Item.Body.Text);
}
```

It will get this exception

`This operation isn't supported on attachments`

I tried binding to the exchange service with item ID.

It also gives me some exception!
Please give some advice on how I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Jin,

The exception you are getting has to do with the property set you are creating. I don't see your code for getting the items so I can't determine the exact cause. I was able to get the following code to work on my machine. You should be able to modify it for your needs.

```
// Return the first ten items.
ItemView view = new ItemView(10);

// Set the query string to only find emails with attachments.
string querystring = "HasAttachments:true Kind:email";

// Find the items in the Inbox.
FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, querystring, view);

// Loop through the results.
foreach (EmailMessage email in results)
{
    // Load the email message with the attachments
    email.Load(new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.Attachments));

    // Loop through the attachments.
    foreach (Attachment attachment in email.Attachments)
    {
        // Only process item attachments.            
        if (attachment is ItemAttachment)
        {
            ItemAttachment itemAttachment = attachment as ItemAttachment;

            // Load the attachment.
            itemAttachment.Load(new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.TextBody));

            // Output the body.
            Console.WriteLine(itemAttachment.Item.TextBody);
        }
}
```

For each email that had an item attachment I was able to see the body of the item with the HTML tags removed.

I hope this helps. If this solves your problem, please mark this post as answered.

Thanks,

--- Bob ---

Comment: Thanks for you codes. But I don't think my program can work with _TextBody_ property since my Exchange Server is 2010. If I am not wrong, _TextBody_ is for Exchange Server 2013. I changed my codes to `PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet();`                   `propSet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;`
`itemAttach.Load(propSet);` It doesn't work either. But this time, no exception found! I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: I changed a couple of lines of code in my example, similar to what you did, and I was able to output the body of the message. The issue still remains that the HTML tags are not removed so you would have to parse the text. Here is another post that shows how to remove the HTML tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878452/remove-html-tags-in-string

Comment: Thanks Bob! I will consider about parsing. Right now, there is very little probability that attachment can be _ItemAttachment_ based on my observation.

Comment: One other thing to keep in mind is that when you determine that the attachment is an _ItemAttachment_ you will also want to make sure that the attachment is an _EmailMessage_ item type.