# Convert @Html.Raw to string in ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

What I want is to convert the output IHtmlString to String.

I have this code:

```
string text = @Html.Raw(Model.lastNoticias.Descricao);
```

This code return the error:

Cannot implicitly convert type System.Web.IHtmlString to string.

The full code:

```
@{ 
    string text = @Html.Raw(Model.lastNoticias.Descricao);
}
@if (text.Length > 100)
{
    @(text.Substring(0, 100) + "... ");
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `string text = Model.lastNoticias.Descricao;` ?

Comment: The Model.lastNoticias.Descricao is an encoded html. I need to decode It and after get the substring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@if (Model.lastNoticias.Descricao.Length > 100)
{
    @Html.Raw(Model.lastNoticias.Descricao.Substring(0, 100) + " ...");
}
else
{
    @Html.Raw(Model.lastNoticias.Descricao);
}
```

Also note that you don't want to trimmed an escaped string. You never know what you are trimming. The solution here does it correctly.

Comment: Than you need to remove html tags. Or you need to complete unclosed html tags when you trimmed. Here is the code you need to complete unclosed tags: https://gist.github.com/kad1r/b92454f76e5b8c017b2e

Comment: But the problem is that Model.LasNoticias.Descricao.Length is an encoded html. If I make the solution above, It will be count the html tags too.

For example: 

`
@{ string h = "<spam>teste</spam>"; }
@("The h value is: " + h.Substring(0,5))
`

The result is:

` <spam `

What I want is get the decoded text and get the substring values.

Comment: basically, what I want is get the decoded text and after test if it > 100 and after get the substring. How can I do it ?

Comment: I told you, you have 2 options for that. First you need to remove all html tags from your string (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878452/remove-html-tags-in-string), second one is trimmed and complete unclosed html tags. The code I gave it to you is doing that, even if you trimmed like "<span>asdaj<sp" it's going to close it. You need to choose one of them.

Answer (score 1):

It's works:

`@{
  string text = "any text";
}
@Regex.Replace(text, @"<[^>]*>", "").Substring(0, 80);`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The question you are answering already has an accepted answer. Your answer does not match the community guidelines and probably should be a comment.