# how to remove tags in text while displaying on a web page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am using TFS API and I try am trying to access a property "Description" of an object "WorkItem"
  I want to display this property on a web page.

When I display this on the web page , this is what I see :

```
<p>This task is created for our SSRS team&#160;Sesame project.</p>
```

Firstly , I wanted to know if this is a html tag or does it mean something else in TFS .
  And secondly , is there a way I can display this in plain text ?

```
 This task is created for our SSRS team Sesame project.
```

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove tags, see this simple solution (it uses Regular Expressions):
[Remove HTML tags in String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4878506/1955346)

It could be even better if you create it as a extension method.

Answer (score 0):

This is HTML as the System.Description field is an HTML one.

If you just write the field out to a  tag it should render as text without the tags. The browser hosting the webpage will render them like any other HTML tags.

Comment: I am using MVC & I  used Server.HtmlDecode on the description item in my controller. I still see that the <p> tags rendered on my html page . Would you have any code samples for this ?

Comment: I am still new to mvc4 . I have posted my code here.. Can you please have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998510/format-a-webgrid-in-mvc4-with-html-helper