# format a webgrid in mvc4 with html helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, webgrid

I have the following web grid.

```
selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);}
<div id="gridContent">
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
        headerStyle: "header",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        selectedRowStyle: "select",
        columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("TaskID", "TaskID"),
        grid.Column("TaskDesc", " Task Desc", format:  @Html.Raw(task.TaskDesc)),
        grid.Column("TaskTitle", "Task Title", style: "description")

 ))
```

This line :

```
    grid.Column("TaskDesc", " Task Desc", format:  @Html.Raw(task.TaskDesc)),
```

gives me an error. Is there a way I can use `@html.Raw` helper within the webgird without it throwing an error ?

Comment: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

 Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string, System.Func<dynamic,object>, string, bool)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Can you output the description outside of the grid?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
grid.Column("TaskDesc", " Task Desc", format:  (item) => Html.Raw(item.TaskDesc)),
```